# Screenless Non-Portable Music Player with digital output

Tags: audio

I'm looking for a device that will play music files like flacs and mp3s, and output them digitally through SPDIF or USB, while not needing a screen to control it. (Having a basic LCD would be acceptable, but not preferred.) I don't want it to be portable, having a battery and such.

Imagine it having the simplicity of a traditional CD player, but able to play files and navigate folders.